# Result appears in firefox console but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, console, response

I have a javascript/jQuery/PHP/mySQL application that has a bug that I've yet to find.  What happens is the response from the submit of a form is visible in the "console" window of firebug but not the browser window.  I realize this is a rather vague question but I'm hoping that might be a common known condition that this represents.

Comment: It is not. You need to show code.

Comment: It sounds like the form may have been submitted via ajax, in which case it's entirely down to the JavaScript on your site as to whether the form values are displayed, ignored, or used in some other way.

Comment: True!  The form is submitted via ajax.

Comment: I guess I may have to break-down and build a small/stripped down version of the code to post.

Comment: searlea, your comment triggered enough to lead me to what was going on.  If you want to submit it as a answer I'll can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug will show the interpreted code and browser(view source) will show the code that you have typed.